# Which of those parameters is default in DBCC SHRINKFILE command?

Tags: sql-server

I know shrink isn't a good practice, but if I execute only ie: `dbcc shrinkfile (filename,1024)`, which is the default? `notruncate` or `truncateonly`? I didn't find anything about it in documentation.

> NOTRUNCATE Moves allocated pages from a data file's end to unallocated
> pages in a file's front with or without specifying target_percent. The
> free space at the file's end isn't returned to the operating system,
> and the file's physical size does not change. Therefore, if NOTRUNCATE
> is specified, the file appears not to shrink.
>
> NOTRUNCATE is applicable only to data files. The log files are not
> affected.
>
> This option isn't supported for FILESTREAM filegroup containers.

....

> TRUNCATEONLY Releases all free space at the file's end to the
> operating system but does not perform any page movement inside the
> file. The data file is shrunk only to the last allocated extent.
>
> target_size is ignored if specified with TRUNCATEONLY.
>
> The TRUNCATEONLY option does not move information in the log, but does
> remove inactive VLFs from the end of the log file. This option isn't
> supported for FILESTREAM filegroup containers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default behavior is to do neither of those things. Both of those modifiers to the `DBCC SHRINKFILE` command change the default behavior.

By default, `DBCC SHRINKFILE` will move data to the start of the file (in data files), then release free space from the end of the file (in both log files & data files).

The `NOTRUNCATE` option will only move data to the start of the file (in data files), without releasing free space from the end of the file. Because log files don't move data within the file, this option isn't meaningful when used on transaction log files.

The `TRUNCATEONLY` option will only release free space from the end of the file, without moving any data within the data file. Because log files don't move data within the file, this actually *is* the default behavior for log files.